# Mustache null value

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have an array of objects which have a key with a value that can be either true, false or null.

```
var a = [
            {
                something: true
            },
            {
                something: false
            },
            {
                something: null
            }
        ];
```

And Mustache should cover all of those cases in different way.

For example, for true it should print:

```
 <a>true</a>
```

For false:

```
 <p>false</p>
```

and for null:

```
 <span>null</span>
```

Is there a way to write an if/else statement for 3 different types of values in Mustache?

Comment: You probably want to use functions in the Mustache hash. Check [this example](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Mustache functions to solve it. You can add a method to the object that will be passed to the Mustache.render method:

Basically you need to iterate through the object to add new method, so you end up with something like this:

```
var a = [
            {
                something: true,
                somemethod: function () {
                    return function (text) {
                        if (this.something === null) {
                            return "<p>" + text + "</p>";
                        } else if (!this.something) {
                            return "<a>" + text + "</a>";
                        } else {
                            return "<span>" + text + "</span>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                something: false,
                somemethod: function () {
                    return function (text) {
                        if (this.something === null) {
                            return "<p>" + text + "</p>";
                        } else if (!this.something) {
                            return "<a>" + text + "</a>";
                        } else {
                            return "<span>" + text + "</span>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ];
```

And later on you can use the following in the template:

```
{{#somemethod}}this text will be used{{/somemethod}}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simpler way is like this:

```
{{#parentId}}{{.}}{{/parentId}}{{^parentId}}null{{/parentId}}
```

In the above example, `parentId` is output if it has a value, and the literal text `null` is output if it is not.